FTDI Port cannot be displayed under the ports (COM and LPT) of Device Manager
We use FT232 for communication between master and slave computers through USB to RS232 serial port. We used the driver of FTDI, but we customized it our own driver by wrapping it outside of FTDI. Our drivers mainly include two inf files: FTDI Bus and FTDI Port. The matter is that the device manager is unable to recognize the COM port. Our Port cannot be displayed under the ports (COM and LPT) of device manager.
Currently, it can only be displayed on 2 sets of ASUS laptops (Windows 11 Home Chinese version, Intel Core i3, X64) under the device manager ports (COM and LPT). Tried other brands like Lenovo, Hua wei, Dell, Hassee, Haier, even if other same model of ASUS laptops but all failed, it won't work. Including desktop computers. Currently the Labview program that is nearly finished will be unable to deploy to the client's machine due to this driver issue.

This does not feel like a programming question. Can you show readers that, in fact, it is?

it might be related to driver programming, such as C language.  Thanks

I think this is going to be a better fit for Super User - you are using regular OS drivers and are not intending to compile your own.

Sorry. Super User, Do you mean install the drivers by administrator privilege? thanks

Well, insofar as I can understand the question, it sounds like the kind of non-programming question that would be better at Super User. However I doubt it is on-topic anywhere, since the problem cannot be replicated. Readers would need to see what logs you're seeing. Is this a serial communication problem?

What is Labview? Can you see logs where it is trying to initiate a serial connection? Is there a place where you can configure the serial comms e.g. port, speed, etc?

Just put the hard disk of my Development ASUS laptop to another same model ASUS laptop and then the later ASUS laptop could recognize the COM port and run my project as on my Development ASUS laptop. This could just temporarily solve the problem. But not long term and ultimate solution. thanks

So sorry just find your 2 replies only after I sent a new comment and refreshed the web page. It is a USB ( converted to RS 232 ) COM serial connection for legacy COM serial device.

I checked the Super User which is really a big topic. Need time to narrow down a suitable place there. Yes. the problem cannot be replicated and not stable on even the same PC when installing the driver.

Again, you need to find logs of the failing serial communication before you can post. This will help you narrow down the problem a lot.

Labview is a development platform for automation test. Not sure whether it has a log before.  I can configure the serial comms e.g. port, speed within my Labview project but all on the condition that my driver could be installed correctly that appear under COM/LPT of the Device Manager. thanks!

My problem does not lie in serial communication at run time. It is the installation of the driver we developed. If our driver can be installed correctly , then it will be no problem for my Labview project to find the COM port and proceed a correct USB to  serial communication .

That is a very late point in the conversation to make clear that you're developing your own drivers! OK, well it may be better here, in that case. But I will keep reminding you that there is nothing for readers to go on until details are supplied.
